# Saving Mutiple arrays with strong parameters Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have an ajax response like this ,

> google_searched_locations [{"geometry":{"location":{"J":31.482273,"M":74.33069999999998}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles
>   /place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png","id":"b93a99a46343de01d0d928f99470f9b0f5f6f11d","name":"Dunkin' Donuts"
>   ,"place_id":"ChIJSeoh6hkEGTkRsd0e1crAbHU","rating":4.3,"reference":"CnRhAAAAewgE30hrAcax1xdGPIf7M863
>   bOtNhRgfnncMx17uWMgtdTyGHGbTO76LX6yXsPyB4PcvfVzIeeIR1bxG0oSambqMYxFWwqHY3Cyfs6uWFp2QbVkGObvQ1LlTrdqLh1eZVgX8aL0iRFFhAnHEM8u1RxIQACDCn2BMD3IiG7tKri31BRoULMSagTU-EmxswgLxzCOWPVVnlpI"
>   ,"scope":"GOOGLE","types":["restaurant","food","point_of_interest","establishment"],"vicinity":"Lahore"
>   ,"html_attributions":[]}]

After JSON.parse(thisString) , I get the required result by using params["places"][0]["geometry"] and then looping over it , but I know that it's not a better way when Rails have strong parameter there , so I tried some solutions after searching , below is my strong parameters function

```
def google_places
    json_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(JSON.parse(request.body.read) )
json_params.require(:google_searched_locations).permit(:icon)
end
```

but it gives the following error ,

> JSON::ParserError in SearchesController#searchResults
>
> 757: unexpected token at 'places=%5B%7B%22geometry

Can anyone make us out of this mess , and tell us what's happening here and where is the right way to go .
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manually parse JSON parameters. Rails will automatically parse the parameters provided the request has the correct format (more specifically the correct mime type headers). In fact doing so will be slower and use more memory since you are doing the same parsing work twice.

To allow an array of parameters you simply use the hash key and an array of the permitted attributes for the nested params.

```
def google_places
  params.permit(places: [:icon, { location: [:H, :L] }])
end
```

If possible you should change the `H` and `L` parameters to lowercase so that you can map them directly to attributes without violating the ruby conventions of lowercase attributes.

Comment: Well are you sure that you are sending the right params?

Comment: yes I'm sure and the reason of my assurity is that i'm inserting these values in db right now , but not through strong parameters

Comment: Well  - `{"places"=>"` is not valid JSON. That's what the JSON::parser error is telling you.

Comment: pardon me for communication gap . i updated my question with actual ajax request . kindly have a look

Comment: That's not valid JSON either. You might want to try validating it http://jsonlint.com/. I guess It might make it easier if you could show  the javascript where you are sending the AJAX request.